# Script to enable mouse shadow?

Tags: windows, vbscript, cursor

I've found people asking this question on some forums, but no solutions. This is a small but annoying cosmetic problem many people know.

Some full screen programs disable the shadow under the cursor in Windows. The shadow usually comes back, but when is doesn't (for example the program didn't close normally) the mouse appears without shadow, and you have to go and manually enable it back.

The solution I'd like to do is a *.bat* or *.vbs* to enable the shadow, only I haven't figured how.

What I did find is that it's a registry value, and there is also something to do to "refresh" the cursor and make the shadow appear. Can anyone help?

I'd like to add that I have very small experience in *.bat* or *.vbs* writing, so if you know what to do and how, please post the **how** too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's located in the famous (yet undocumented :-) "**UserPreferencesMask**" registry key.
Here are some pointers:

A first general link with information on this key, and how the mouse shadow setting is defined: [HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop\UserPreferencesMask](http://www.msfn.org/board/topic/73209-hkcucontrol-paneldesktopuserpreferencesmask/page__p__578901#entry578901)

And a sample that explain how to code it using VBSCript (it's another key, but the principle is the same): [Set UserPreferencesMask Binary Registry Key](http://www.cb-net.co.uk/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=32%3avbscript--set-userpreferencesmask-binary-registry-key&catid=10%3avbscript&Itemid=8)

Comment: Thanx, but the problem is it takes effect only after another logon.

Answer (score 4):

Using the API makes it take effect immediately.

```
#include <Windows.h>

int main() {
    BOOL didSucceed = SystemParametersInfo(
        SPI_SETCURSORSHADOW,
        0,
        (PVOID) TRUE,
        SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE + SPIF_SENDCHANGE);

    return didSucceed ? EXIT_SUCCESS : EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```